# Trying to follow a shell scripting tutorial, receiving "$: command not found"

Tags: linux, shell

I'm following this guide here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Every time I run: `$ [ -f /etc/passwd ] && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exists"`

I get:

```
$: command not found
File does not exists
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do not copy the `$` symbol. It represents the prompt.

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot now. That fixed it. Thanks for the help. If you want to snag the answer go ahead and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, we've all done something similar at some point ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most tutorials, the symbol `$` or `%` is used to represent your shell prompt, which could look like anything. Only copy stuff after the `$` symbol.